# Can't get Celery run_every property to work

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm trying to create some Celery Periodic Tasks, and a few of them need to have the ability to change the run_every time at runtime.  The Celery documentation says I should be able to do this by turning the run_every attribute into a property (http://packages.python.org/celery/faq.html#can-i-change-the-interval-of-a-periodic-task-at-runtime).

Here is what I'm doing:

```
class ParseSomeStuffTask(PeriodicTask):

    def run(self, **kwargs):
        # Do stuff

    @property
    def run_every(self):
        if datetime.now().weekday() in [1, 2, 3]:
            return timedelta(minutes=15)
        else:
            return timedelta(seconds=40)
```

Unfortunately, when I turn on celerybeat, I get the following error:

> [Thu Sep 09 15:44:40 2010:
>   CRITICAL/828]: celerybeat raised
>   exception :
>   'datetime.timedelta' object has no
>   attribute 'is_due'

It then shuts down.  The Celery documentation doesn't really go into what to return when making run_every a property, and I haven't had any luck searching Google.  Celery changelogs say its been able to change a Periodic Task's interval at runtime since version 1.0.0.

Dev. Environment:

- Python 2.6.5
- Django 1.2.1
- Celery 2.0.2

Comment: So run_every is represented by a single property that has to return a timedelta. Somewhere in your code it has to be leveraging is_due just like your error is showing. The code above seems like that should work as expected. Unless I'm missing something about where is_due is being performed.

Comment: Does it work when you change it to a fixed timedelta (instead of using a property descriptor)?

Comment: Yeah, works fine then.  I can comment out the property I made and add run_time = timedelta(seconds=40) under that class declaration.  Then I can't change it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Celery 2.0 supports different schedule behaviors. There's `celery.task.schedules.schedule` and `celery.task.schedules.crontab`.

You have to return one of these, or make your own subclass of schedule.

```
from celery.task.schedules import schedule

@property
def run_every(self):
    if datetime.now().weekday() in [1, 2, 3]:
        return schedule(timedelta(minutes=15))
    else:
        return schedule(timedelta(seconds=40))
```

The `run_every` attribute will be automatically converted at instantiation,
but not later.